# Bootstrap - Center Align Image in the tablet view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row that shows 3 images in a row on a desktop view

```
[1] [2] [3]
```

On a tablet view, it appears like

```
[1]  [2]
[3]
```

What I want is 3rd image to appear in the center and not on the left of the second row (on tablet)

classes on my divs containing images are

`col-md-4 col-sm-6`

Ideas ??

Comment: @whosoverdownvoted : Why did you vote it down. Reasons??

Answer (score 0):

You have have several options for this, however there is one seen below:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        Container 1<img src="http://www.gifbin.com/bin/092010/1283335170_fat-cat-eating.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        Container 2<img src="http://www.gifbin.com/bin/092010/1283335170_fat-cat-eating.gif">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-md-12 center">
        Container 3<img src="http://www.gifbin.com/bin/092010/1283335170_fat-cat-eating.gif">
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dzhfe7Lr/3/)

**Large Screen Behavior**

[1]  [2] [3]

**Medium Screen Behavior**

[1]  [2]
   [3]

**Small and XSmall Screen Behavior**

[1]
[2]
[3]

The all containers will span the whole area (i.e. 1/3, 1/2, or whole section) however because it will auto align to the left so you need to add a centering option, text-center on the row works in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">[1]</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">[2]</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">[3]</div>
```

It will appear on desktop view:

```
[1]    [2]    [3]
```

And on tablet view:

```
    [1]     [2]
        [3]
```